# Scoped Variables : Explanation for the code ouput?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Why is the output of the following snippet undefined, 5?

```js
var a=5;
(function(){
    console.log(a);
  var a= b = 10;
  
})();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: this behavior is named as Hoisting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called hoisting in javascript. Hoisting means that all the variables which are declared inside a scope a brought to the top of the scope and declared there and then assigned on their corresponding line.

The above code is same as

```
var a=5;
(function(){
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a= b = 10;
  
})();
console.log(a);
```

In the above function when `var a;` is declared but not initialized so it will get assignment to `undefined` automatically. Hence you see `undefined` in the first log.

And in the second log you see `5` because the previous variable `a` is inside that function and not available outside. In the outside log the `a` in global scope will be logged.